# Reading static variable from a binary

Tags: c, security, debugging

I am trying to read the value of a static variable in C like:

```
int variable = value;
```

The thing is that I only have the binary, and the code with a fake value (it is for a lecture, where we study security aspects of software development).

I have been trying to read the value using the [GDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Debugger), and

`(gdb)info variables`

which just gives me a list of the variables (including the one I'm looking for) and what seems to be an address, so I would like to know if there is a way to read the value using GDB?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In GDB, use the '`print`' command:

```
print variable
```

Voila!